# Why was my tag deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I'm an iOS developer and I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655480/using-cocoapods-with-multiple-platforms) question yesterday. It's about the dependency manager for Objective-C, Cocoapods. I created the tag **Podfile** because it didn't exist and it was removed by someone who calls himself "a proud member of the New Tag Deletionist Cabal" without mentioning no reason whatsoever.

I thought that tag was reasonable comparing a lot of pointless ones out there. Podfile is a major component used in Cocoapods. It's where you mention all the dependencies. There's a separate set of syntax to do so as well. Basically I think most of the questions asked about Cocoapods have to do something with the Podfile.

Can anyone tell me why was this removed and what do you have to do to get a new tag approved?

Comment: [Maybe he's trying to make you ragequit so you can bounty him all your rep.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175402/a-user-ragequit-after-bountying-me-all-his-rep-and-im-kind-of-creeped-out-by-i) :D:D:D

Comment: @Isuru, I feel your [pain](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254132/2507539).

Comment: For the many users who aren't iOS developers or are otherwise unfamiliar, maybe explaining why the tag is needed would be helpful.

Comment: @Mysticial lol that's crazy. I mean, I'm completely okay with people editing my questions and all. But explaining it would be nice. I wish people who are in the particular field gets to edit questions related to their field.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I added some more info about it.

Comment: @Isuru thanks... so one question `Basically I think most of the questions asked about Cocoapods have to do something with the Podfile`.... this makes it sound like something tagged with [tag:cocoapods] will likely be about a podfile.  So does it really need to be a separate tag?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yeah, if you look at it that way. I just wanted to have a more specific tag. Didn't think there was any harm in that.

Comment: @Isuru it might be a valuable tag, I don't know enough about it to say for sure, but just getting to obvious questions out of the way.  But is sounds like it could possibly be redundant.

Comment: @psubsee2003 hm.. I see. This is why I think it's best people from one field get to edit the questions of their expertise would be a great idea. Eliminates all the confusions and everything.

Comment: @psubsee2003 is correct, the 100% conceptual overlap between `cocoapods` and `podfile` is one of two reasons why I remove that tag -- and even have it on the list of **271** tags I keep dead, as someone creates it a few times a quarter.  The other is that the concept of a "pod file" is one shared between multiple languages and envrionments, including but not limited to Perl's documentation format, POD.  It would end up being ambiguous as spelled.

Comment: @Isuru: neat idea. I look forward to an expert in "anroid" arising who will be allowed to remove that tag under your "only experts can edit" policy.

Comment: @Charles Just throwing this out there, but maybe it would be good to publish that list of tags along with an brief explanation on why they're burned?  Then people would have a reference to point to in the future when people ask why a tag was deleted.  Hmm... make that a community wiki and then people could curate the list.

Comment: @Rakuen42, I've been lazily working on a site to actually help me take care of this task.  The SE team recently put a restriction on the number of tags you can search for at once, so I have over a dozen individual bookmarks I visit multiple times a day.  It's a burden on the resources provided by the site, and it's a pain in the ass for me.  It'll happen eventually.  Hopefully it can be used by everyone doing a burnination, to help keep all of them deaded.

Comment: For better or worse, there are both [tag:make] and [tag:makefile] tags.

Comment: @JonathanDursi, how I wish that the synonym proposal system wasn't completely broken...

Comment: Sounds like the tag should be cocoapods-podfile

Comment: Is it *your* tag, or *our* tag?

Comment: @Charles: broken in what way?  Can you expand on that?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, synonyms can be proposed by and voted on by people with a certain minimum score in the tag that will become the synonym.  It's difficult to impossible for normal users to create synonyms of low-traffic tags.

Comment: @Charles: based on the "tag score", right.  Question: when you get an upvote on an answer, does that count towards every tag on the question, or only the primary tag?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, as far as I know, upvotes count for all tags, not just the primary.  Some people have previously cheesed the system by retagging a handful of questions they've answered, waiting for a tag score recalc (usually nightly but bugged as of late), and then voting for a synonym.

Answer (score 17):

What does the tag `podfile` tell us that `cocoapods` doesn't?

Put another way, would someone follow the `podfile` tag to find all new questions tagged `podfile`? Or would they (more likely) follow the broader tag, `cocoapods`?